# How to setup the relationship for these tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

1 Course have at least 1 lecture

1 Lecture can have 0 or more Tutorial

1 Lecture can have 0 or more Lab

1 Tutorial can have 0 or more Lab

This is how my tables are setup for the moment:
[image: This is how my tables are setup for the moment]

I have encounter 2 different situations for courses:

1 - for a given lecture, you have 0 tutorial, but 2 labs sections (you choose only 1 lab) --> so 1 lec + 1 lab
2 - for a given lecture, you have 2 tutorials, and 2 labs associated with each tutorial --> so 1 lec + 1 tut + 2 labs

My structure will fail for situation #1 (since 0 TUT will brake the link between LEC and LAB)

---

Alternative structure (as propose by octern):

COURSE - LEC

LEC - TUT

LEC - LAB

The problem with this is: how do I determine if student has to take 1 or 2 labs?

Answer (score 0):

If the rules you described were exactly accurate, then the relationships you proposed would be right. "1 Tutorial can have 0 or more Lab" means that every lab is related to (at least?) one tutorial. But when you say, "this would fail if a lecture doesn't have a tutorial but only a lab," you're indicating that the rules don't accurately model the situation. You're saying that labs are related to *lectures*, not tutorials. So the foreign key on both `TUT` and `LAB` should be `lec_id`.

Comment: Thank you octern, with the structure you proposed, how do I determine if student has to take 1 or 2 labs?

Comment: How would that have been determined in your previous model? Right now I don't see anything in the database that talks about what students need to sign up for.